# Why I get error trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried to create Mysql trigger by query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `Delete Video` AFTER DELETE ON video 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
DELETE FROM usersalbumsvideo where id_video = OLD.idVideo; 
DELETE FROM categorytovideo where idVideo = OLD.idVideo; 
END
```

But I get error:

```
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4
```

Tried also to swap `id_video = OLD.idVideo`, anda an one `DELETE`

Comment: The error message pretty much says why you get an error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that the problem is your delimiter, looking at [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html) page I think that your query should be:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER `Delete Video` AFTER DELETE ON video 
  FOR EACH ROW 
  BEGIN 
  DELETE FROM usersalbumsvideo where id_video = OLD.idVideo; 
  DELETE FROM categorytovideo where idVideo = OLD.idVideo; 
END;//
delimiter ;
```

Comment: @PiligrimBilim thought so. consider accepting the answer if it was acceptable to you.